# multiple sql files deployment

Tags: deployment, cicd

I have 100 sql files in one folder  In azure devops Repo

FIRST CASE:
-i want to  execute and deploy all sql files    to Azure sql databse deployment task in azure build and release pipeline.
SECOND CASE:
based on requirement I want to deploy some files like 10 or 20 sql files from that folder contained 100 files  in single package or batch file to deploy in azure database using azure build and release classic pipelines

CASE:3
i want to Rollback the packages

I want to deploy required sql files as a single package from other folder containing 100 sql files and need to deploy azure sql database task using azure build and release pipelines